# Is it possible to read from BigTable async?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

BigTable hbase API has the BigTable.get() function to read a list of gets. Sometimes this action can take quite a long time (like 100ms). I wonder if there is anyway we can get a future for it so that we can use this 100ms to do something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have an asynchronous API available at the HBase layer since the official HBase APIs are synchronous.

However the underlying gRPC API is actually asynchronous: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-client/javadoc/com/google/cloud/bigtable/grpc/async/package-tree

Also you might want to look at the **asyncbigtable** library created by the OpenTSDB folks: 
https://github.com/OpenTSDB/asyncbigtable